# How to make two arrays in two columns

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a different array cons made of the first 5 constants of the alphabet and print both arrays, vowels and cons in two columns.

This is the code given:

```
    char vowel[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};

    for(int i=0;i<vowel.length;++i)
    System.out.println(+(i+1)+". " + vowel[i]);
```

I did this:

```
    char cons[]={'b','c','d','f','g'};
    for(int j=0;j<cons.length;++j)
    System.out.println("["+j+"] ->" + cons[j]);
```

But I need the output as this:

```
    1. a b
    2. e c
    3. i d
    4. o f
    5. u q
```

Comment: You should add to the existing code, according to those instructions. So you should have two arrays. One loop only. Don't change the part that prints the number and the vowel. Only add the part that prints the data from the second array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know both arrays have same length, you could use a single `for` loop and print both `vowel[i]` and `cons[i]` at the same time in the same line.

If you don't know that both arrays have same length, you could loop from 0 to `min(vowel.length, cons.length)`.

And keep in mind that it's better to add `{ ... }` to your `for` instructions to avoid surprises ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array is of length 5, you don't have to use the length(), its just an overhead. Use length() only when you don't know what the length of the array is.

```
char vowel[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
char cons[]={'b','c','d','f','g'};

    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
        System.out.println(+(i+1)+". " + vowel[i] + " " +cons[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
char cons[]={'b','c','d','f','g'};
char vowel[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
for(int i=0;i<vowel.length;i++)
System.out.println("[" + vowel[i] + "->" + cons[i] = "]");
```